# QString character erase function

Tags: c++, qt, qstring

```
QString line = "example string";
```

Now I want to erase the space between 'example' and 'string' so that I get a string like this "examplestring". Is there a function in Qt which erases a character under the given index or should I write this function myself ?

Comment: Did you look at the [QString reference](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qstring.html)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
line = line.remove(index,1);
```

see the [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qstring.html#remove)

Answer (score 12):

What about `QString::remove(QChar ch, Qt::CaseSensitivity cs = Qt::CaseSensitive)` function? You can use ' ' as a first argument. I.e.:

```
QString line = "example string";
line.remove(' ');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
line.replace(QString(" "), QString(""));
```

Comment: Yes , but as far as I understand it will replace all the " "-s with "" , but what I want is to erase only one space.

Comment: That is correct. In that case, you can use @ratchet-freak 's method, you just replace `index` with `8`, this is the index where your space is located inside the string.